# I need to sort list of movies that are AVAILABLE to rent

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have my method which sorts all the movies in the array (dArray) of class dvd. now i need to sort available movies (setAvailable == true) ONLY. the array is dynamically filled in by customers entering movies from the menu. my code currently searches through the array and sorts all movies from A to B but now i want it to search and sort only the movies whereby d.setAvailable(true)... Thanks for your help. much appreciated

here is the sorted list of all the movies in the array:

```
if(e.getSource() == sortMovBtn)
        {
            if(dArray[0]==null)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No movies, please enter\na movie from the main menu","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            else
            {
                BtnPanel.setVisible(false);
                imgPnl.setVisible(false);
                btnBackDvd.setVisible(true);
                txtAreaSortDvd.setVisible(true);
                sortDvdPnl.setVisible(true);
                Dvd tmp;

                for (int i = 0; i < manyDvd; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < (manyDvd - 1 - i); j++)
                    {
                        if (dArray[j].getTitle().compareTo(dArray[j+1].getTitle()) > 0)
                        {
                            tmp = dArray[j];
                            dArray[j] = dArray[j+1];
                            dArray[j+1] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                a = "";
                for (int k = 0; k <manyDvd /*dArray.length*/; k++)
                    a += (dArray[k]);
                txtAreaSortDvd.setText(a);
                txtAreaSortDvd.setVisible(true);
                txtAreaSortDvd.setEditable(false);

                //Set font of text area
                txtAreaSortDvd.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));

                //Initialize JScrollPane
                JScrollPane pane1 = new JScrollPane(txtAreaSortDvd);

                //Enable user to use wheel on mouse to scroll
                pane1.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);

                //Set the scrollbar to always show
                pane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

                //Add ScrollPane to Panel
                sortDvdPnl.add(pane1);

                //Add panel to frame
                add(sortDvdPnl);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Please remove all code not **directly** related to the question. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Add all the available movies to a new list, sort and show that one?

Comment: How are you displaying the information to the user?  Note that a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) has inbuilt functionality to [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSorter%28javax.swing.RowSorter%29) a [`DefaultRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html) that can also filter entries.

Comment: how do i add the available movies to a new list?

Answer (score 3):

First, you shouldn't have code to work with your model (data) mixed in with UI code.

Second, you should not be sorting the data on the UI thread. Do the work on a background worker thread.

Third, you should not be coding up the sort yourself, especially not like that. Your sort is O(n^2). There are good options for sorting in java.util.Arrays for arrays or java.util.Collections for the collection classes.

There are two basic ways to go about sorting just the items that meet a certain criterion. You could sort the entire data set with a custom Comparator, matching first by the criterion and second by the rest of your sort criteria. Then your results would be at the start of the data, and you would only show the results until the first item that does not meet the criterion.

This has the advantage that it uses no extra space beyond what is already required to store your data.

A cleaner way would be to make a copy of just that portion of the data that meets the criterion, and then sort that. It would also be much easier to work with if the data was in a List instead of an array, since you would not need make two passes over the data: one to find out how many items match the criterion, and one to filter out the matching items. (In between, you would allocate an array to hold them.)

Suppose your data was in a List. You could get the available movies like this:

```
public List<Movie> getAvailable(List<Movie> movies) {
    List<Movie> avail = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    for (Movie movie : movies) {
        if (movie.isAvailable()) {
            avail.add(movie);
        }
    }
    return avail;
}
```

You could then sort these movies (in their natural sort order) like this:

```
List<Movie> availOnly = getAvailable(movies);
Collections.sort(availOnly);
```

P.S. In Java 8 you will be able to do something like:

```
Iterable<Movie> avail = movies.filter(Movie::isAvailable).sorted();
```

Comment: Nice answer, upvoted. However about the 'third' above I guess that OP might have a school assignment to learn about writing sort algorithms. That it's a slow algorithm is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

use comparator http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: This won't actually remove the already rented movies from the list.

Comment: Comparator is used for that purpose ,check http://www.digizol.org/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html , you can get the hint

Comment: Correcting above link: http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html